# Web service in C# and consumed from PHP

Tags: c#, php, soap

I have tried to do a webservice in C# and consume from PHP but I can't to do this.

I try to do the following project:
I have a form in PHP which must send data captured through a webservice to database in SQL-Server, currently I have the webservice running, my trouble is when I try to take the data of the form in PHP and send to the database.

This is a example of my code in C#.

```
public bool addData(int AGE, string NAME)
{
    try
    {
        string dataSourceConnection = "Data Source=data;Initial Catalog=servidor;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(dataSourceConnection);
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TEST (AGE, NAME) VALUES ('" + AGE + "','" + NAME + "')", connection);
        object o = command.ExecuteReader();
        return true;
        connection.Close();

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Code in PHP:

```
<?php
require_once 'nusoap.php';
$name = $_POST['NAME'];
$age = $_POST['AGE'];
$webService = new SoapClient('http://localhost:43571/servicioWeb.asmx', array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));
$ws = $webService->addData(array('NAME' => $name, 'AGE' => $age))->result;
?>
```

Can someone please tell me how I can do this?

Comment: If possible, please post your code rather than a screen capture of your code.

Comment: Before you do anything else you need to read about, understand and start utilizing parameterized queries. This is a textbook example of sql injection.

Comment: You also should really do something with your exception. You are handling it ok but if something does happen you can't debug this very easily because the exception got thrown away.

Comment: I fixed your formatting and "imported" your php code. You shouldn't `return` before you close the connection btw. Also we have no idea what `nusoap.php` does.

Comment: To extend what @m02ph3u5 said, you should wrap you connection and command objects in a USING statement so they will be properly be disposed every single time. The way you have this coded you can max out your connection pool because the connection isn't going to get closed.

Comment: Also PHP's `SoapClient` ain't got no method called `addData()` so what's your `SoapClient`? http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php